# Java Graphics2d: how to rotate a dodecagon smoothly using int values

Tags: java, rotation

I use this function to create a dodecagon:

```
private void getPoints(int x0, int y0,int r,int noOfDividingPoints)
{

    double angle1 = 1;

    x = new int[noOfDividingPoints];
    y = new int[noOfDividingPoints];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfDividingPoints  ;i++)
    {
        angle1 = i * (360/noOfDividingPoints);

        x[i] = (int) Math.round(x0 + r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle1)));
        y[i] = (int) Math.round(y0 + r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle1)));

    }

}
```

Then with this I rotate all the points around a center:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SLICES; i++) {
    int x1 = x[i] - center.x;
    int y1 = y[i] - center.y;

    int x2 = (int) Math.round(x1 * Math.cos(radian) - y1 * Math.sin(radian));
    int y2 = (int) Math.round(x1 * Math.sin(radian) + y1 * Math.cos(radian));

    x[i] = x2 + center.x;
    y[i] = y2 + center.y;
}
```

With this I finally draw the lines:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < SLICES; i++) {
        g.drawLine(center.x, center.y, x[i], y[i]);
        if (i != 0 ) {
            g.drawLine(x[i-1], y[i-1], x[i], y[i]);
        } else {
            g.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[x.length-1], y[x.length-1]);
        }
    }
```

**THE ISSUE**:

The dodecagon spins, but the rotation deforms the vertices making the shape slightly irregular; it's altering during the rotation: this happens because of the conversion from double to int done by Math.round().

Without using Math.round() the dodecagon collapses to the center.

How can I use int values without having the shape alteration? Do I have to use doubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not examined your code, but focussed on your observation *"making the shape slightly irregular"* and *"Without using Math.round() the dodecagon collapses to the center"*. You are accumulating the errors of the calculation. You have to rewrite the code so you are accumulating the rotation angle and then for the display you do one calculation based on the original shape. That way the round (or truncate in case of the int conversion) does not accumulate.

I.e. instead of

```
X = X * RotationStep
```

for every step you do

```
Rotation += RotationStep;
X = originalX * Rotation
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. As soon as I have time I'll try to fix it.